# Transverse momentum in partonic process $\gamma^\ast q\rightarrow qg$

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, vectors, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

Let $\hat{s}:=(q+p)^2$, $\hat{t}:=(k-p)^2$, $\hat{u}:=(p-p^\prime)^2$ be the Mandelstam variables of the partonic scattering process $\gamma^\ast(q) +q(p)\rightarrow q(p^\prime)+g(k)$, where the momenta are given in the brackets and it is assumed that the quark is massless. Furthermore, let $Q^2:=-q^2$, as is custom.

I want to show that the gluon's transverse 3-momentum $\mathbf{k}_T:=\mathbf{k}-(\mathbf{k}\mathbf{p})\mathbf{p}$ fulfills the equation
$$\mathbf{k}^2_T=\frac{\hat{s}\hat{t}\hat{u}}{(\hat{s}+Q^2)^2}.$$

Using the partonic Bjorken variable $z:=Q^2/(2pq)$ and the fact that $\hat{s}=Q^2(1-z)/z$, I find that
$$\frac{\hat{s}\hat{t}\hat{u}}{(\hat{s}+Q^2)^2}
=z(z-1)\left(\frac{\hat{t}}{z}+\frac{\hat{t}^2}{Q^2}\right).$$

For the transverse 3-momentum I find that
$$\mathbf{k}^2_T=\mathbf{k}^2+(\mathbf{kp})^2(\mathbf{p}^2-2).$$
Via the equation $\hat{t}=-2kp=-2E_kE_p+2\mathbf{kp}$, this can be expressed as

$$\mathbf{k}^2_T=\mathbf{k}^2+\frac{1}{4}(\hat{t}+2E_kE_p)^2(\mathbf{p}^2-2)=E^2_k+\frac{1}{4}(\hat{t}^2+4E^2_kE^2_p+4E_kE_p\hat{t})(E^2_p-2),$$
where $E_k,E_p$ are the energies of the gluon and incoming quark respectively.

But from here on I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the centre-of-momentum frame of the gluon and the quark let
\begin{align}
p&=(a,0,0,a),\\
q&=(q^0,0,0,-a),\\
p^\prime&=(b,b\sin\theta,0,b\cos\theta)\\
k&=(b,-b\sin\theta,0,-b\cos\theta).
\end{align}
From here it is easy to see that $\mathbf{p}_T=(b\sin\theta,0,0)$.

Since $Q^2=-q^2$ we have $q^0=\sqrt{Q^2-a^2}$. For the Mandelstam variables we find
\begin{align}
\hat{s}&=(p^\prime+k)^2=4b^2,\\
\hat{t}&=-2pk=-2ab(1-\cos\theta),\\
\hat{u}&=-pp^\prime=-2ab(1+\cos\theta),
\end{align}
which gives us $\hat{s}\hat{t}\hat{u}=b^2(4ab)^2\underbrace{(1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta)}_{=1-\cos^2\theta}=(4ab)^2(b\sin\theta)^2=(4ab)^2\mathbf{p}^2_T$.

Also, 
$$\hat{s}+\hat{t}+\hat{u}=2pq-Q^2-2pk-2pp^\prime=2p(\underbrace{q-k-p^\prime}_{=p})-Q^2=-Q^2,$$
which entails that $\hat{s}+Q^2=-(\hat{t}+\hat{u})=4ab$.

Thus,
$$\frac{\hat{s}\hat{t}\hat{u}}{(\hat{s}+Q^2)^2}=\mathbf{p}^2_T.$$